# Problem with testing void HttpRequest

Tags: apex, unit-test, httprequest, httpcalloutmock, httpresponse

I can only get 23% code coverage with what I have. The http request in the method is not getting covered for some reason..
Here's what I've tried:

Class:

```
public class PostClientes {
    @InvocableMethod(label ='Llamada nuevo cliente')
    public static void llamarnuevoCliente(List<Account>cuenta)
    {
        Id idcuenta = cuenta.get(0).id;
        
         NuevoCliente(idcuenta);  
    }    
    
    @future(callout =true)
    public static void NuevoCliente(ID idCuenta ) {
        
        
        List<Account> acc = [SELECT Name, Phone,PersonMobilePhone,Direccion__c,Profesi_n__c,Estado_Civil__c,Email_Lugar_de_Trabajo__c, Description,Identificacion__c,Sexo__c,PersonBirthdate,Departamento__c,Municipio__c,Nacionalidad__c,Beneficiario__c,Funcionario_P_blico_de_Alta_Jerarqu_a__c,Fecha_de_Inicio_de_Relaci_n__c from Account where id = :idCuenta];
        Account cuenta = acc[0];
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('myEndPontCantShowIt');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        //Cuerpo de la  request
        //request.setBody('nombre=JosuePueba&celular=8807-0422&telefono=2272-4851&direccion=Afuera&foto=N/A&profesion=ingeniero&estado_civil=soletro&email=chale@chale.com&nota=descripcion&cedula=0012407001030J&sexo=Mas&fecha_nac=N/A&departamento=M&municipio=M&indentificacion=1&nacionalidad=salvadorena&beneficiario_final=N/A&funcionario_publico=N/A&usuario_actual=administrador&fecha_ingreso=N/A&cargo_fp=n/a');
        
        request.setBody('nombre='+cuenta.Name +'&celular='+cuenta.PersonMobilePhone +'&telefono='+ cuenta.Phone+'&direccion='+cuenta.Direccion__c +'&foto=N/A&profesion='+ cuenta.Profesi_n__c+'&estado_civil='+cuenta.Estado_Civil__c +'&email='+cuenta.Email_Lugar_de_Trabajo__c + '&nota='+cuenta.Description +'&cedula='+cuenta.Identificacion__c +'&sexo='+cuenta.Sexo__c+'&fecha_nac=' +cuenta.PersonBirthdate +'&departamento='+cuenta.Departamento__c +'&municipio='+cuenta.Municipio__c +'&indentificacion=1&nacionalidad='+cuenta.Nacionalidad__c +'&beneficiario_final='+cuenta.Beneficiario__c +'&funcionario_publico='+cuenta.Funcionario_P_blico_de_Alta_Jerarqu_a__c +'&usuario_actual=administrador&fecha_ingreso='+cuenta.Fecha_de_Inicio_de_Relaci_n__c +'&cargo_fp=n/a');
        
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
       //Respuesta del servidor
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {  
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        

    }
}
```

My Tests:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponsePOSTClientes implements HttpCalloutMock {
      global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        res.setBody('nombre=JosuePueba&celular=8807-0422&telefono=2272-4851&direccion=Afuera&foto=N/A&profesion=ingeniero&estado_civil=soletro&email=chale@chale.com&nota=descripcion&cedula=0012407001030J&sexo=Mas&fecha_nac=N/A&departamento=M&municipio=M&indentificacion=1&nacionalidad=salvadorena&beneficiario_final=N/A&funcionario_publico=N/A&usuario_actual=administrador&fecha_ingreso=N/A&cargo_fp=n/a');
   
          
        return res;
    }
}
```

Test aswell:

```
@isTest
public class PostClientesTest {
   @istest
   public static void PostClientesTestMethod (){
         
        
        Test.startTest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
       
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponsePOSTClientes());
        PostClientes.NuevoCliente('00105000004I3LeAAK');
        
        Test.stopTest();
     
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine that you're probably running into an exception like "List index out of bounds: 0" when you run this test.

You haven't inserted any `Account` records as part of your test method. That, and your hard-coded account id will not exist when you run the test (unless you specify seeAllData = true, which you should basically *never* do as it breaks test data isolation). Even if it did exist in one org (production or a sandbox), it will never exist in another org (unless it's a full or partial copy sandbox).

Long story short, hard-coding Ids is a red flag, and should be avoided.

When writing unit tests, you are responsible for setting up the data your test needs to be able to run.

In this case, that means creating a test account, inserting it, and then passing that Id (i.e. something like `testCuenta.Id` instead of a hard-coded Id value like '001000000000001AAA') to the method you're testing.

Comment: Thannks for the explanation, it worked!

Comment: @JosueRivas A little bit more information... If you are indeed seeing that exception, that's because your query returned no results. The list you're storing the results in is empty, so `acc[0]` (the first element) does not exist. All things considered though, using a list (or more generally, a collection) to hold the results is safer than storing it in a single variable. If you have something like `Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account];`, you'll get an error if the query returns no rows (no rows for assignment) or more than one row (more than one row for assignment).